# W3C validation: 'there is no attribute "DATA-FLEXMENU"'

Tags: html, w3c-validation

> Line 30, Column 57: there is no attribute "DATA-FLEXMENU"
>
> ```
> … href="about.php" class="mainlink" data-flexmenu="flexmenu1">About Us</a></div>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the current doctype you're using doesn't support the data-flexmenu attribute.

You should either take the data-flexmenu attribute out of your href, switch to an HTML5 doctype (it supports the data attribute), or just live with the error.